# How to properly implement ModalRoute In flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

On the [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html) 
i came across this `ModalRoute` class, but I couldn't find any cookbook or tutorial that talked about it in greater depth.

Can anyone explain what it is and how we can use it in our application?

Comment: I also can't find a way to implement it :(